# Forbid already used values with QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, qfield

currently i am working on a mapping solution for a NGO fighting NTD's. The goal is to locate unique patients due to their identificationcode. Since the mapping will be done by a bigger group of people with the help of QField, I want to prevent the input of false or doubled values by using a value map where the certain patientcode can be selected. After the selection, I already set up some autofill-functions so the staff can check if the patient-code belongs to the correct person before saving the input.

Now I am trying to find an expression with which I can **forbid** the input of a **already used codes** since they are all pretty similar to each other. Unfortunatly i am not to good in writing expressions. Does anybody have an idea how I could solve this problem?

I am working on QGIS 3.28.3.

Comment: I think it'd be process-wise easier to let each user collect data on their own, upload it each evening and then one "admin" transfers the data to the whole collection, thus permitting double IDs. Otherwise you get all the issues with synchronising data you can get. Another option would be to create unique IDs based on patient location, name and age, but that would lead to privacy issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a "Unique" constraint on the field. This prevents a feature being added unless the particular field has unique values. It can be combined with the value map you are already using.

[image]

[image]